# Class property attribute for intellisense?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Let's say I have this class...

```
Public Class Person
    Public Property Gender As String = "male"
End Class
```

And I do this...

```
Dim p As New Person
p.Gender
```

... and hover the mouse over "Gender", then intellisence shows me ....

> Property.Person.Gender As String

Can I somehow add an attribute to the Gender property to show more intellisence help - like...

> Property.Person.Gender As String = "male"

Or maybe...

> Property.Person.Gender As String
>
> It is default set to 'Male'

I was hoping to do smething like...

```
Public Class Person
    <Intellisence="It is default set to 'male'">
    Public Property Gender As String = "male"
End Class
```

Thanks

Comment: How about tag as `visual-studio` or even specific the version, instead of `c#` or `vb.net`

Comment: Good point - updated my question.

Comment: I don't have visual studio installed in my pc, but maybe you take a look in XML (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx), `<summary>` or `<remark>` may help

Comment: @Alex as I see it summary is on the entire class - I want to add extra info for the intellisence per property.

Comment: Can you test this class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z04awywx.aspx), it have set the `summary` for the property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the XML comment to achieve that.

All tags are listed in Microsoft website: [C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx) and [VB.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172653.aspx)

More example can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z04awywx.aspx

Back to your question, you can set the summary tag in your property, e.g.:

```
Public Class Person
    /// <summary>
    /// It is default set to 'Male'</summary>
    Public Property Gender As String = "male"
End Class
```